# how to avoid unauthorized access exception?

Tags: c#, sql, getfiles, unauthorizedaccessexcepti, getdirectories

The following is my code.

```
 //string[] directories; 
        List<string> dirs = new List<string>(Directory.EnumerateDirectories("C:\\Users\\Josh"));
        //string[] Files;

        //directories = Directory.GetDirectories(@"C:\Users\Josh\", "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

        SqlConnection myConn = new SqlConnection("Server=Josh-PC;database=Music;User ID=Josh; Password=Climber94; Trusted_Connection=True;");

        string removeText = "Delete from Music.dbo.SongNamesAndInfo";
        SqlCommand RemoveEntry = new SqlCommand(removeText, myConn);

        myConn.Open();

        RemoveEntry.ExecuteNonQuery();

        myConn.Close();

        //for (int d = 0; d < directories.Length; d++)
        foreach (var dir in dirs)
        {                            
            List<string> files = new List<string>(Directory.EnumerateFiles(dir));

            foreach (var file in files)
            {

                FileInfo oFileInfo = new FileInfo(file);

                myConn.Open();

                string cmdText = "Insert INTO Music.dbo.SongNamesAndInfo " +
                        "(Name,dtCreationTime,Extension,Length,DirectoryName)" +
                        "VALUES(@Name,@dtCreationtime,@Extension,@Length,@DirectoryName)";

                SqlCommand addCmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText, myConn);                    
                DateTime dtCreationTime = oFileInfo.CreationTime;

                addCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", oFileInfo.Name);                                       
                addCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dtCreationtime", dtCreationTime);                    
                addCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Extension", oFileInfo.Extension);                    
                addCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Length", oFileInfo.Length.ToString());                    
                addCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DirectoryName", oFileInfo.DirectoryName);

                if (oFileInfo.Extension.ToLower() == ".mp3" || oFileInfo.Extension.ToLower() == ".avi" ||                    
                    oFileInfo.Extension.ToLower() == ".mkv" || oFileInfo.Extension.ToLower() == ".m4a" ||                        
                    oFileInfo.Extension.ToLower() == ".aac" || oFileInfo.Extension.ToLower() == ".wav" ||                        
                    oFileInfo.Extension.ToLower() == ".mpa" || oFileInfo.Extension.ToLower() == ".wma" ||                        
                    oFileInfo.Extension.ToLower() == ".flv" || oFileInfo.Extension.ToLower() == ".m4v" ||                        
                    oFileInfo.Extension.ToLower() == ".mpg" || oFileInfo.Extension.ToLower() == ".mov" ||                        
                    oFileInfo.Extension.ToLower() == ".wmv" || oFileInfo.Extension.ToLower() == ".mp4")                        
                {                            
                    addCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }

                myConn.Close();                    
            }
```

so what im doing is taking a list of music and movies and placing there properties into a sql data base but i want it to search all the directory's in the user file. due to the appdata im getting a

> System.UnauthorizedAccessException was unhandled.

how can i avoid this? the error is  where it is pulling all files from the user folder Josh.

Comment: is the app running as an administrator, or at least a user who has permissions on the directories in question?

Comment: yes. it is the only account on the computer. and being the app data folder i dont need it to search it beings it is a hidden folder.

Answer (score 4):

Some files are system files (such as the ones in User folder as in your case like AppData etc). you can either request permission or ignore them

```
        FileIOPermission f = new FileIOPermission(PermissionState.Unrestricted);
        f.AllLocalFiles = FileIOPermissionAccess.Read;
        try
        {
            f.Demand();
            //your code for processing files
        }
        catch (SecurityException s)
        {
            //cannot get permissions for files.got exception
            Console.WriteLine(s.Message);
        }
```

i suggest you to take a look at Code Access Security 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/930b76w0(v=vs.85).aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0d005ted(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: how exactly am i suppose to use this.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Directory.EnumerateDirectories](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383304(v=vs.110).aspx) in order to access each folder one at a time and either ignore or log the ones that throw exceptions.  This way you'll get as much as you can.

If you want to know how to get permission to a directory, that's a matter of your user account's permissions.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the enum [Environment.SpecialFolder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx).
 use `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyMusic )`  for music folder or `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile ) + @"\Downloads";` etc specifically.This is because ideally you won't get access to all folders and sub folders in the Windows explorer itself in the user folders. That is where it throws the exception.
so your code would be something like this

```
        string[] directories;
        string[] Files;
        string folder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyMusic ) ;
        directories = Directory.GetDirectories(folder);
```

Comment: i do want all folders and sub folders minus system folders. this is going on a server so that i have an easy way to find what movies and music i have. currently it is not all organized because i have several people back up to it.